# images from database via php can't display

Tags: php, image

thank's for help. I have problem displaying images retrieving from my database.

I cant see the image when loading image.php in img src or directly from the page. When i display the variable without `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` i can see all the code inside, as i put this line all goes off.

I have a table called TABLE with id, title, img stored as longblob directly uploaded inside phpmyadmin.

Can anyone help me?

```
index.php 


<?php
session_start();
include "admin/include/connection2.php";

$data = new MysqlClass();

$data->connect();

$query_img ="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY data ASC LIMIT 4";
$post_sql = $data->query($query_img);
if(mysql_num_rows($post_sql) > 0){

  while($post_obj = $data->estrai($post_sql)){
  $id = $post_obj->id;
  $titolo = stripslashes($post_obj->title);
  $data_articolo = $post_obj->data;
  $immagine = $post_obj->img;

// visualizzazione dei dati
echo "<h2>".$titolo."</h2>";
echo  "Autore <b>". $autore . "</b>";
echo  "<br />";



echo '<'.'img src="image.php?id='.$post_sql['id'].'">';
echo $id;



echo "<hr>";
  } 
}else{

echo "no post aviable.";
}


// here is the image.php code


<?php

include "admin/include/connection2.php";

$data = new MysqlClass();
// connect
$data->connetti();
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articoli_news WHERE id='".$id."'"; //even tried to     send id='1' but not working
echo $query;
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['id']; //correct displaying

$content = base64_decode($query['img']);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

 echo $content;



?>
```

Comment: Try this- >

 
 $img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($query['img']));
 imagepng($img, "test.png");
 imagedestroy($img);

Comment: You can't `header()` since you've already `echo`ed. Use file to debug.

Comment: 1. I think your id is number but you put that into quotes.
2. Your mysql_query function closing paranthesis is missing.

Comment: i tried with '' and without, result is it's the same. header's () is ok, i didnt copy in this post.

Comment: ps for Jerin, same result with your code. can't understand what i'm missing, i tried 15 different solution and no way. can anyone post me a sure functioning script so i trythat? many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all "echo" commands except "echo $content;" because there are also appear in the output, and damage your image.
And use ob_start(); in the begining of the script, and check out your script file not contain any of whitespace characters before or after the php begint and close tags  .

Comment: Hi adee thanks for answer, unfortunately not working, i repost image.php code as i intended:

Comment: ups sorry:

<?php
ob_start();
include "admin/include/connection2.php";

// istanza della classe
$data = new MysqlClass();
// chiamata alla funzione di connessione
$data->connetti();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articoli_news WHERE id='1'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = base64_decode($query['immagine']);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $content;
?>

Comment: I see that you upload from phpmyadmin I think you do not need the base64_decode. echo the $query['img'].

Comment: i have to answer by comment cause i'm a new user here,anyway...
Not working even in this way, what's wrong?? :(   my basic code now is: 

    <?php
    ob_start();
    include "admin/include/connection2.php";

    $data = new MysqlClass();
    // chiamata alla funzione di connessione
    $data->connect();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='1'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $content = $row['img'];
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $content;
    ?>

Comment: another thing, i see in the html code generated by image.php this tag, is it correct? 
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/veronica_cavallini/image.php">